# Detect app termination to clear ongoing notification

Tags: android, service

My service has an ongoing notification which is active while the service is active (to indicate that the service is running), and I'm clearing the notification in `onDestroy()` of my service.

But if the app is cleared from the "recent applications" list, my service's `onDestroy()` does NOT get called! How can I clear the notification?

Answer (score 0):

Change your service to a bound service, android will then call onDestroy on your service when the last activity that calls it is destroyed (unless, as per the Android documentation, the service was started by startService()).

Comment: the service is started from my activity (upon established connection)

Comment: Adnan, I apologize, the last part of my answer was confusing.  If you look up the Android documentation to bound services, you will see that they are intended for exactly what you want, for the bound service to be terminated by the system when your app is.

Answer (score 0):

Android will call onDestroy if you add

```
<service android:name=".yourservice"
         android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```

to your manifest.